# VB.net Word document : update the section numbers after adding a new section

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, interop

I am copying section 8 of word document and pasting it at the end of section 8. After that I replace some words in the just pasted section. After that, I have to again copy section 8 and paste it at the end of section previously pasted (i.e. section 9).

The problems is, intially i have sections upto 10, when I copy and paste section 8 first time, it pastes correctly, but when I paste second time, it is pasted at the of 10th section and not at the end of recently pasted section.

Below is my code, I am using "`goto`" to place cursor at the end of section and increment the section number.

```
 Function copyPasteSectionInWord(copysectionnumber As String, PastelastOfThisSectionnumber As String)

    Dim sectionInFocus As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Section
    Dim secRange As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range

    sectionInFocus = wordDoc.Sections.Item(copysectionnumber)
    secRange = sectionInFocus.Range
    secRange.Copy()

    wordApp.Selection.GoTo(What:=WdGoToItem.wdGoToSection, Which:=WdGoToDirection.wdGoToNext, Count:=PastelastOfThisSectionnumber)
    'secRange2.Collapse(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
    'secRange.Paste()
    wordApp.Selection.Paste()
    'wordDoc.Fields.Update()

    'secRange.Collapse(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
    releaseObject(secRange)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below is in VBA but demonstrate one way of achieving your goal.  Please note that this code just inserts new sections and copies text from a particular section to the new sections.  It does not do any editing of sections.

```
Sub InsertSectionsandPopulateWithText()

    Dim myRange As Word.Range
    Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Sections.Item(8).Range
    myRange.Collapse direction:=wdCollapseEnd

    myRange.InsertBreak Type:=WdBreakType.wdSectionBreakNextPage
    myRange.InsertBreak Type:=WdBreakType.wdSectionBreakNextPage

    With ActiveDocument.Sections
        .Item(9).Range.FormattedText = .Item(8).Range.FormattedText
        .Item(10).Range.FormattedText = .Item(8).Range.FormattedText
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Great.  But it was a crude solution.  Your next task is to remove the dependency on magic numbers (e.g. 8,9,10) so investigate the range.next property.